# Simple Javascript/JQuery Cookie Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I've got an animation that I want to play only once and I figured that since the animation was in JQuery, the function to write the cookie file should be as well.

So far I've got:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if (!$.cookie('cookieName'))
 {
    setTimeout(function() {    
    $('#intro').fadeOut(1000); 
 }, 5000);
};

$.cookie('cookieName', 'the_value');

});
```

I guess I was thinking this was going to check to see if there was a cookie and if not then play the animation. When that was done it writes a cookie and so when I come back to the page it doesn't play. I'm calling the Klaus Hartl cookie plugin and for some reason this just isn't doing it for me.

Much appreciated.

Comment: I think this cookie code is bogus. I was getting cookies set with the same code one day and the other day it was just making session cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the code for that plugin. I think you might need to specify options and the expiry when you create the cookie. Something like this:

```
   var date = new Date();
   date.setTime(date.getTime() + (3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
   $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, 'test', { path: '/', expires: date });
```

Code ripped off the plugin site :) - http://stilbuero.de/jquery/cookie/

Comment: Im beginning to think the problem is with the plugin, but no one else is making a big deal about it so Im inclined to think Im the one whos wrong.

In the http://stilbuero.de/jquery/cookie/jquery.cookie.js - documentation for the plugin</a> they say:


  @example $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');


* @desc Set the value of a cookie.

Isnt that what Im trying to do (and doing) above?

Comment: I took a quick look at the source code, I think by default the expiry is set to -1 days, which I believe removes the cookie right away. You should try the above. Just add the first 2 lines before you call $.cookie. And call $.cookie with the third parameter like above.

Comment: Yep. works like a charm.
Wish they SAID that default was -1 in the docs, but there isnt a lot online about it. Thanks for the eyes.

Comment: By default, the cookie plugin doesn't set an expiration and the cookie expires at the end of the session. It only sets expiration to -1 if a null value is passed, in order to delete the cookie.

Comment: but it didnt create a cookie file locally without the var date = new Date();
   date.setTime(date.getTime() + (3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

Maybe I misunderstand a session cookie, but if I dont close the browser then the session should still be open.

Answer (score 0):

I would download the [Web Developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) for Firefox and use it to examine the cookies. Can you see it being made locally?

It could also be, if 'the_value' is something falsy, it won't work. For example, if the value was '0', I think that would evaluate to false.

Comment: didnt even know the dev bar had a cookie tool. Cool.

Uhh.. no. I dont see it being made locally. Does this mean im not calling the JS plug in correctly?

Comment: Perhaps not. Make sure your scripts are in this order (top to bottom): jQuery, jQuery Cookie Plugin, your script

Comment: My scripts are in the right place if thats the order.
Is the syntax off in the If statement?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
alert($.cookie('cookieName'));
```

and see if it has a value on it.

or

have you tried

```
if($.cookie('cookieName') == null) { 
// do your thing
// then set cookie and put a great amount of days in the expire param
}
```

Comment: The code for 
if($.cookie('cookieName') == null) works

but Its still not making the cookie that I can see in the Dev bar when i use $.cookie('cookieName', 'the_value'); to specify cookieName + Method